# Speed improvement in the mid point circle algorithm

Tags: algorithm, geometry

Does the speed of the mid point circle algorithm improve if we divide the circle into 16 parts rather than the 8 parts given in the general algorithm.please give explanation for either case

Answer (score 2):

If you divide circle into 16 pieces rather than 8, you make 1 extra mirroring operation while decreasing the mirrored pie to half. If performance gain due to halving the pie is greater than the extra-mirroring slow-down, then you should use 16 pieces.

Dividing circle into 2 parts:

```
 1 x 180degree computing and 180degree mirroring.
```

Dividing circle into 4 parts:

```
1 x 90degree computing and 
90degree mirroring x1 
180degree mirroring x1
```

Dividing circle into 8 parts:

```
 1x 45degree computing and 
 1x 45degree mirroring.
 1x 90degree mirroring.
 1x 180 degree mirroring.
```

Dividing circle into 16 parts:

```
 1x 22.5degree computing (half of before) +performance
 1x 22.5degree mirroring.(an extra from before) -performance
 1x 45degree mirroring.
 1x 90 degree mirroring.
 1x 180 degree mirroring.
```

its like exchanging 22.5 degree mirroring with 22.5 degree calculating

But, mirroring smaller angles is more complex than mirroring 90degree angles.

Comment: if cpu is bottleneck then -performance bigger. if memory is bottleneck then +performance is bigger.